# How to implement chatbot in my mobile application

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I am trying to find any open source platform using which i can implement chat-bots in my application. I have done RND on this but no luck. If some one already done something like this and implemented chat-bot in his/her application. Then please help me out here. Please send me some links using which i can implement chat-bot in my application. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Basically, Chat-bots has two parts. 1) natural language processing and ii) chat backend system(like push notifications, chat status, online/offline presence, typing indicator, forwarding etc).

For first part, you can use any of NLP APIS like one from [google](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=2016-q3-cloud-apac-IN-SKWS-freetrial-en&gclid=CLfk68-u3M8CFdiIaAod5YYBMg),[Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/apis) etc. It totally  depends on your usage case and business which apis suits you best.

For second part, you can use any of the chat backend service like [Applozic](https://www.applozic.com/) or build your own. For Client side implementation, you can explore our open source client repositories [here](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-iOS-SDK).

PS: I am co-founder at applozic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Botlibre](https://www.botlibre.com/). They provide android api with documentation for implementing a chatbot. However first you have to create a chatbot there and use credential to connect from android.